# Angular2, Typescript and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

Been trying to get Angular2, TS and VS2015 to play together. I probably would have been quicker building a bridge between London and New York.OK, Angular2 is still in alpha but the documentation is pityful (it wasnt much better for Angular1) and typescript.

I've sort of got there but I am having a problem importing internal modules. It seems ok at design time but when I run i get a 404...

```
import {Component, bootstrap, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor, NgIf, NgClass, View} 

from 'angular2/angular2';
//import {HeroService} from '../ng-app/services/heroservice';
import {HeroComponent} from '../ng-app/components/heroComponenet';
import {EmptyService} from '../ng-app/services/EmptyService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor, NgIf, NgClass],
    templateUrl: '../../ng-app/templates/heroTemplate.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../css/heroes.css']
})
@View({
        directives: [HeroComponent],
        template: '<div><hero-component></hero-component></div>'
})

class App {}
bootstrap(App, [EmptyService]);
```

and the error

[image]

I guess I'm not really understanding how module loading should work!!

thanks

Comment: Can we see all the code? Its hard to tell by just a snippet. However did you notice the spelling in your bottom screenshot? *heroComponenet* The names don't have a file extension either. Also Angular should be throwing an exception when you specify both a `template` and `templateUrl`, you can't have both.

Comment: Hi, the names don't need a file extension, the spelling was consistent throughout. I ended up using an Asp.net 5 (rather than 4.6) project and got it to work that way... (bower, node etc rather than nuget)... I haven't seen anyone use an angular2 and VS 4.6 project and get it to (still) work with latest releases (as amongst other things the type definitions don't compile/are out of date etc)